# Django <img> not working but the static file is accessible via url

Tags: django, heroku, static, static-files, whitenoise

I'm trying to put an image in the html code, using:

```
<img scr="{% static "degustos/empanadas.jpg" %}" class="card-img-top" alt="Empanadas Ilustrativas"/>
```

but the image isn't displayed.
On the other hand, I can access the image going to http://localhost:8000/static/degustos/empanadas.jpg

My settings.py:

```
 MIDDLEWARE = [                                                                                                                                                                                                       
     'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',                                                                                                                                                                 
     'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',                                                                                                                                                                    
     'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',                                                                                                                                                          
     'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',                                                                                                                                                                     
     'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',                                                                                                                                                                     
     'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',                                                                                                                                                       
     'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',                                                                                                                                                          
     'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',                                                                                                                                                        
  ]       


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')                                                                                                                                                                  
STATIC_URL = '/static/'                                                                                                                                                                                              

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]                                                                                                                                                                

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

It's deployed in Heroku.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll kick yourself. You've got `scr=` instead of `src=`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below

```
<img src="{% static "degustos/empanadas.jpg" %}" class="card-img-top" alt="Empanadas Ilustrativas"/>
```